# Why isn't ownership transferred in the name field of this structure?

Tags: rust

```
struct People {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = People {
        name: String::from("john"),
        age: 24,
    };
    println!("{}", s.name); //1

    s.name = String::from("kk");

    println!("{}", s.name); //2
}
```

My understanding is that `s.name` entered `println` at position 1, so there should be a transfer of ownership and an error, but there isn't. Why?

Comment: Why should there be an error? You assign a new `name`. Also, `println!()` just borrows its arguments, not moves them.

Comment: sir, is that `s.name` doesn't change ownership  in `println`? But I remember in the chapter on ownership, without `&`, the ownership of the compound type would have changed.

Comment: `println!()` is a macro. It adds the `&` automagically for you. But even if it wouldn't, this would still work as you're assigning a new `name`.

Comment: finally got it! thank you!